# Help with error: The file 'MainWindow.xaml' is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'

Tags: wpf

Oddly enough, googling this error doesn't produce any results.

Is there any quick fix for this bug / known causes?

The file's build action is Page like the rest of my xaml windows, and it is definitely part of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a button click eventhandler that wasn't pointing to the correct method.